# router-link won't load page

Tags: vuejs3, routerlink, vue-router4

Can't find what I am doing wrong. If I type the url on the browser the page does load, but the links from the navbar do nothing. I am trying three different ways to use router-link, but makes no differences. It just won't render the page via link. No errors on the console. On the vue devtools the routing displays the correct path.

App.vue:

```
<template>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <router-link :to="{ path: '/' }">Home</router-link>
      <router-link :to="{name:'TheDashboard'}"> Dashboard</router-link>
      <router-link to="/games">Games</router-link>
    </nav>
    <router-view></router-view>    
</template>
```

router/index.js:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import TheHomePage from '@/pages/TheHomePage'
import TheDashboard from '@/pages/TheDashboard'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'TheHomePage',
    component: TheHomePage
  },
  {
    path: '/dashboard',
    name: 'TheDashboard',
    component: TheDashboard
  },
  {
    path: '/games',
    name: 'TheGames',
    component: () => import(/*webpackChunkName: "games" */ '@/pages/TheGames.vue'),
    props: true
  },
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes
})


export default router
```

main.js:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from '@/App.vue'
import router from '@/router'
import store from '@/store'


const prototype = createApp(App)
prototype.use(router)
prototype.use(store)

prototype.mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 5):

In the end this was a bug caused by Vue devtools. I removed previous versions and updated to latest, and it is now working. Nothing wrong with the code. I thought I might as well leave the code here, since it might be helpful for other people.

Comment: This was bugging the hell out of me. I had a fresh install of VueJS v3. And the vie-router was doing exactly as you described. This fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks been looking for a solution for a while now and it turns out the my vue-devtools was the issue

Answer (score 1):

your code seems optimal to me. However, you can use the `beforeEach` and `afterEach` hooks to help you to debug your App.

you can read about them [here](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#beforeeach)

do something like:

```js
//router/index.js

//...
//const router = ...

router.afterEach((to, from, failure) => {
  console.log('to: ', to);
  console.log('from: ', from);
  if (isNavigationFailure(failure)) {
    console.log('failed navigation', failure)
  }
});

export router;
```